Color code sf points object by category in R
I am trying to color code an sf points object in R, but can't quite figure out how to do it. I want the NAs to show up as a separate category. Here is the code I have so far.
dat = data.frame(utmn = c(45,46,47,48,49),utme = c(1,2,3,4,5),cat = c("A","A","B","B",NA))
points = st_as_sf(dat,coords = c("utme","utmn"),remove = FALSE, crs = 32606)

points <- points %>%
  mutate(category = ifelse(is.na(cat), "NA",cat))

ggplot(points) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = cat)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlGnBu",na.value="grey") +
  labs(title = "Map by Category")

As you can see, it still shows up just black

You were on a right track with the na.value argument of ggplot color scale.
What you need to change is mapping - from fill to color. Fill aesthetic works the best for polygon insides, while points are usually mapped via color; fill is defined only for a few special shapes (shape number 19  to 25; have a look at the very last example in ggplot2 docs).
So with a slight adjustment in ggplot aes call + scale fill to scale color you get this; note that I am also changing the NA color to red to make it stand out a bit more in the default ggplot setting.
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(utmn = c(45,46,47,48,49),utme = c(1,2,3,4,5),cat = c("A","A","B","B",NA))
points = st_as_sf(dat,coords = c("utme","utmn"),remove = FALSE, crs = 32606)

ggplot(points) +
   geom_sf(aes(color = cat)) +
   scale_color_brewer(palette = "YlGnBu",
                      na.value="red") +
   labs(title = "Map by Category") 


